# FileOutputStream can't find any file

Tags: android

this doesn't gives any error but I can't any file in sdcard.
what do I do wrong?

```
      File photo=
          new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                   "photo.jpg");

      if (photo.exists()) {
        photo.delete();
      }

      try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());

        fos.write(jpeg[0]);
        fos.close();
      }
      catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
      }

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: "but I can't any file in sdcard" -- how are you looking for it? DDMS? Your desktop OS's file manager? **`adb shell ls`**? Some on-device file manager? Something else?

Comment: DDMS and usb connected sdcard

Comment: I checked around "/storage/emulated/"

Comment: Some devices really messed things up, the path to the SD card might differ depending on the protocol you use to access the file system. Check `/sdcard`, `/storage/emulated/0` and for `external`, `external_sd` or something similar in these directories.

Comment: I practically looked every folder at level 1 and 2, nothing there

Comment: I checked both nexus 4 and zenfone 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DDMS and **`adb shell ls`**, external storage would be, by default, at `/mnt/shell/emulated/0/`.

To get your file to show up quicker in other tools, like file managers, you should call `getFD().sync()` on your `FileOutputStream` between your `flush()` and `close()` calls, then use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method to let `MediaStore` know about your new file.

And, please get rid of the `android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` `<uses-permission>` element, as there is no such permission.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation of `getExternalStorageDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()):

> Return the primary external storage directory.

Notice the word *primary* (ie. there may be more).

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

This means some devices can have more external storages with the primary not being SD card (they may also have external storage and no SD card at all). You should still be able to access this storage when you plug your phone to your computer.

Also you can obtain path of the file with `File.getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: The path reported by `getExternalStorageDirectory()` is how the app's process accesses external storage, which does not necessarily line up with how other tools, like DDMS's file explorer, accesses external storage. This, unfortunately, gets confusing.